# Splash Screen showing after returning from background (iOS 8 only)

Tags: ios, ios8

I noticed that my application shows the splash screen for a fraction of a second(it depends of the complexity of the view when the application goes background) every time I return from background, the issue is on iOS 8 only.

What I tried to do (ideas from similar but older SO questions):

- Do absolutely nothing when returning from background.
- Remove "Status bar is initially hidden" and "Status bar style" from plist file.

I also noticed the same behavior on other apps but was solved after updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague came up with a solution : use an asset catalog to set launch images according to screen size and orientation.